# node.js-like technology on PHP

Tags: php, websocket, comet

I tried to make long-polling with PHP myself, but it works terrible and eat a lot of processor time.

Is there any ready solutions of keeping a lot of connections (for comet or websockets) using PHP?
Something like node.js or erlang?

Comment: I've heard @deceze recommending, on questions like such, Gearman: http://gearman.org/ . However, I'm not sure if you can get the same results (and performances) as nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to node.js on php is [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/).  Here are some [benchmarks](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/11/benchmarking-codswallop-nodejs-v-php) that compare the performance of node.js to ReactPHP.

If you're working with websockets and looking for something closer to socket.io, but for PHP.  I would suggest taking a look at [Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) (I'm one of the developers).

Thruway is built on top of Ratchet (websocket library) and ReactPHP (event loop).  It simplifies getting websockets working with PHP and gives you RPC and SubPub via the [WAMPv2](http://wamp.ws/) protocol.